# React: Function adds data twice to localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am creating a shopping cart and use the below function to take data on the selected product and add it to `localStorage`. I then use this data stored in `localStorage` to show the user the items they selected. Everything works, but I have an issue with this function sending duplicate data. So everytime I add an item and the function runs, `localStorage` shows me that the previous item was added twice. Any reason why this might be happening?

```
const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);
let itemsInLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'));

const addToCart = (selectedItem) => {
    let array = cartItems;

    if (!array.includes(selectedItem)) {
        array.push(selectedItem);

        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
        setCartItems([ ...cartItems, selectedItem ]);
    } else {
        console.log('Already added');
    }
};
```

Comment: And how do you call `addToCart()`?

Comment: If `cartItems` in `localStorage` is the same as the `cartItems` state in your component, why are you using a different array for `localStorage`? Just use `[ ...cartItems, selectedItem ]` for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the state - that can cause unexpected behaviour.

```
let array = cartItems;
```

`cartItems` is an array, `let array = cartItems` is a reference to the same array.

```
array.push(selectedItem); --> modifies cartItems
```

```
setCartItems([ ...cartItems, selectedItem ]);
```

You can `cartItems` with `selectedItem`, and then you add it as well.
What you should do:

```
const addToCart = (selectedItem) => {
    let array = [...cartItems];

    if (!array.includes(selectedItem)) {
        array.push(selectedItem);

        localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
        setCartItems(array);
    } else {
        console.log('Already added');
    }
};
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you added function like this `<button onClick="addToCart()" >...` Better would be remove from button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-darwin-zg4p4?file=/src/App.js).

You can use `useState()` to keep the array that needs to be saved to `localStorage` in memory and on every change (adding a new item to the array) you can use `useEffect()` to save the modified array to `localStorage`.

Comment: getting an error on your codesandbox - `TypeError
Cannot read property 'includes' of null`

Comment: Ops, fixed it :)